# How to get the ID of Fragment nested in a Fragment which is already nested in another fragment

Tags: android-fragments, nested

I am trying to build an app based on http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial/

One my fragment tabs contains a google map, so it must be nested in another fragment. But I cannot retrieve its ID, so I cannot load the map. I used:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_map, container, false);
```

And I think the layout should be inflated since I used something similiar for another tab. However when I tried to find the fragment with:

`SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1));`

It returns null. It tried and checked what `getFragmentManager().getFragments()` will give at this point, and its the list of the fragment tabs (tab1/tab2/tab3). When I tried the same command in a different app but having only one fragment nested , I can see the hierarchy of my fragments in the list (mainactivity/tab/map)  and so I can load the map.
Any idea of what I could do? I tried also `getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()` and that returns null too.